# How to autofill form fields with google+ account?

Tags: forms, google-plus

I've got a few landing pages and wanted to add this feature. Basically, a user lands on one of my pages and they're given the option to:

Fill in all data manually or click on the google+ account button
So if they're already signed into their google+
Then the data will autofill the fields on the form (name, email, phone, etc)

Anyone have any insights on this?

Thanks!